Getting error while loading Power BI Embed Report
Getting error while while executing report in power BI embeded

generated Azure AD Auth token
generated Embed token
generated Embed URL for integrating report

Everything went smooth but loading the report by using code in JavaScript gave below error.
Any Suggestions where made mistake?


The problem was in the modelling which can be found inside powerbi desktop Application

Go in particular report open .pbix file in Desktop App
In the Header go to Modeling.
Beneath there will be option for Manage Roles.
So in row level security Applied in report we need to provide effective identity parameter make sure that you assign correct role here.
You can rename to any role there or with any string that yo need to pass in the effective identity.
It was misleading from the error codes in API was asking about Capacity management but by open connection error.


